# label size is not changing for a gnuplot in latex

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I have the following gnuplot script called inside a latex document. I want to change font size of different labels. But it is not changing the font size, is there any suggestions.

```
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex, terminaloptions =  {size 8cm, 6cm}] 
    reset
    set yrange [0.01: 10000000000.0]
    set xtics rotate by 45 right nomirror
    set grid ytics
    unset border
    set title "(a)"
    set macros
    set key top horizontal center
    set logscale y
    set format y "$ 10^{%L} $"
    set label 1 "Variation :" at 771, 680.0 center font "Bold-Times-Roman,24"
    set label 2 "Variation in IPC" at 671, 7 center tc lt 1  font "Bold-Times-Roman,30"
    set xlabel "Ticks" offset 0.5,0   font "Bold-Times-Roman,30"
    set ylabel "Vulnerability [bit*cycle]" offset 2.5,0  font "Bold-Times-Roman,30"

    #plot from file
    plot '../gnudata/matlab_fft/smatlab_ipc.txt' using 1:2 title 'IPC'  with  line linecolor rgb "blue" lw 3

\end{gnuplot}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For latex-based terminals you should use latex commands to control fonts and font styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shell]{gnuplottex}
\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex]
set label 1 "\\Huge This is huge and \\bf bold" at -6,0
plot sin(x)
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For global changes you can specify options to the terminal driver, see `help cairolatex`.